# minecraft client gets timeout when cpu-usage hits 100%

Tags: java, cpu, minecraft

I installed Minecraft on XUbuntu 18.04. I play on a server of a friend to which I connected directly via ip-adress.

I am there for a few seconds, then I get an error and lose connection; usually  it's a TimeOut.

When running taskmanager, I see this happens when cpu-usage hits 100%. (It's an Intel Pentium, if this is interesting.)

How to prevent this?